# I don't exactly know how .equalsIgnoreCase work?

Tags: java, string, compare

I am literally know and get the hang of the java right now and I'm writing the program that helps to records patient'd ID in the Hospital, i'll show the whole code first,then, I will tell where you will, here is the code

```
package hospitalsrecord;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class HospitalsRecord {
public static Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
public static ArrayList nameList = new ArrayList();
public static ArrayList patientAge = new ArrayList();
public static ArrayList Disease = new ArrayList();
public static ArrayList dateHospitalized = new ArrayList();
public static ArrayList roomNumber = new ArrayList();
//adding patient function
    public static void AddNewPatient () {  
    //Ask patient's name
    System.out.println("Please enter patient's name:");
    String patientName = read.next();
    //Ask Patient's age
    System.out.println("Please enter patient's age:");
    int age = read.nextInt();   
    //Ask patient's illness
    System.out.println("Please enter patient's Disease name (also include accidents eg. Leg broke by Car Accident):");
    String illness = read.next();    
    //Ask patient Hospitalized date
    System.out.println("Please enter patient's Hospitalized date(Total days not included):");
    String HPTLdate = read.next();    
    //Ask patient's room number
    System.out.println("Please enter patient's hospitalize room number(3 degits):");
    int HRN = read.nextInt();
    //Confirmation
    System.out.println("Doctor, would you like to confirm the following(y/n)?");
    System.out.println("Name:" + patientName);
    System.out.println("Age:" + age);
    System.out.println("Disease:" + illness);
    System.out.println("Date Hospitalized (HPTLD):" + HPTLdate);
    System.out.println("Room Number:" + HRN);
    String Confirm = read.next();
    if (Confirm.equals("y")) {
      nameList.add(patientName);
    patientAge.add(age);
    Disease.add(illness);
    dateHospitalized.add(HPTLdate);
    roomNumber.add(HRN);
    } else {
        AddNewPatient();
    }
    }
    //Searching patient that listed
    public static void searchPatient (){

    }
    //remove the patient function
    public static void removePatient() {

    }
    //text printing function when strat the program
    public static void selectorPage(){
        System.out.println("Hello Doctor, welcome to Hospital Recorder v1.0.0");
        System.out.println("If you want to add new patient into this recorder type: 'add' in the next blank line line");
        System.out.println("If you want to search the patient list type: 'search' in the next blank line");
        System.out.println("And, if you want to remove the patient that was out of hospitalizing type: 'remove' in the next blank line");
        option = read.next();
    }
    //text printing simmilar to selecterPage function but perform after function
    public static void selecterPageAfterAction() {
        System.out.println("Your action has been performed, doctor");
        System.out.println("Would you like to perform another action?(y/n)");
       choiceSelection = read.next();
       if (choiceSelection.equals("y")){
        System.out.println("If you want to add new patient into this recorder type: 'add' in the next blank line line");
        System.out.println("If you want to search the patient list type: 'search' in the next blank line");
        System.out.println("And, if you want to remove the patient that was out of hospitalizing type: 'remove' in the next blank line");
        option = read.next();
       }  
    }
    //Selection var
    public static String option;
    public static String choiceSelection;
    //Main program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        selectorPage();
        switch (option) {
            case("add"): {
                AddNewPatient();
                break;
            }
            case("search"):{
                searchPatient();
                break;
            }
            case("remove"):{
                removePatient();
                break;
            }
            case("end"):{
                break;
            }
            default: {
                System.out.println("Please enter the indentified option");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("end")){

        }
    }

}
```

I hope you guys can read every line because it was so so so so complex, but for someone who can read all of it, i'll know that you'll say I still need more time for hard working, no worry i'll spend sometime to get most knowledge from you guys first, but still working hard for program to complete while waiting for answers! anyway the point that I want you guys to focus at this point:

```
if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("end")){

    }
```

It maybe too blank because I've just newly add it while i'm working on it. So, what I want to know is at the if statement I type option.equalsIgnoreCase("end"), Am I explain the computer to do the following?

1.Compare the the String variable options with the String"end"?

2.Tell the computer to do the action inside if statement's when the String option wasn't the word end?

And please tell me how this method work, i don't clearly understand it. I understand like this "It compare two strings if it wasn't the same then it's result is true" I know my explanation is wrong so could you please help me? thanks again for helping if you can.

Comment: The casual `String` comparison with `String#equals` is case sensitive, this method compares these two `String`'s case insensitive.

Comment: To clarify further...comparing "Alpha" and "alpha" with String#equals will return false as 'A' is not equal to 'a'. But comparing "Alpha" with "alpha" using String#equalsIgnoreCase will return true because 'A' is equal to 'a' when you ignore case.

Comment: The method only returns true if both strings are equal while ignoring the case of the strings. `"TRUE".equalsIgnoreCase("true");` has the result  `true`.

Comment: `option.equalsIgnoreCase("end")` will be `true` if `option` equals any of the following: `end`, `enD`, `eNd`, `eND`, `End`, `EnD`, `ENd`, or `END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option.equalsIgnoreCase("end") - equalsIgnoreCase will ignore whether string is in lower case or uppercase.

So it will enter into if block only when option variable has either end or END.

Your first assumption is correct, you are asking to compare String whether it is equal to end. But Second one is wrong, from above code it will enter and execute statements present inside if only when option is end/END.

If you want to go inside If block when the option is not end then add a not like this if(!option.equalsIgnoreCase("end")).

I Hope this clears your doubt!

Comment: well, there are more options then `end/END` as of `End`, `ENd` and so on.

Comment: @KevinEsche yes correct, all combinations are allowed

Answer (score 0):

The class `String` has two methods to compare one String to another.

See the example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "beer";
    String str2 = "Beer";

    System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
    System.out.println(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2));                
}
```

The first method `equals()` compares `str1`and `str2`and takes the case into consideration. Hence, the first comparison results in `false`, meaning Beer is not equal to beer.

The second method `equalsIgnoreCase()`does the same, **except** that it is **not** case-sensitive. Result of this comparison is `true`, meaning "ignoring the case, Beer is the same string as beer".

Hope this helps.